# Any Interactive way to manipulate plot data using python ?

Tags: python

Is there any way using python to edit/manipulate a data interactively? That is I want to plot the data and edit the data by dragging the data points in plot by mouse. Is it possible to do this in python?

I want something like this [manipulate-chart-data-with-mouse](https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/manipulate-chart-data-with-mouse/).

Comment: [bokeh](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/) is a very good library for that.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [dash](https://dash.plot.ly).

[This link](https://community.plot.ly/t/moving-the-location-of-a-graph-point-interactively/7161) gives an example of making an editable plot similar to your requirements.